# ZPL using Smartforms

Tags: zpl, sap-smart-forms

```
_CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~
^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR2,2~SD15^JUS^LRN
^CI28
^XZ
^XA
^MMT
^PW799
^LL0519
^LS0
^FT269,285^A0N,40,42^FH\^FD&IV_HEADER&^FS
^FT39,400^A0N,28,25^FH\^FDÜRÜN ADI    :^FS
^FT39,500^A0N,28,25^FH\^FD\ÜRÜN KODU :^FS
^FT39,600^A0N,28,25^FH\^FDLİSANS NO   :^FS
^FT182,400^A0N,30,28^FH\^FD&IV_MAKTX&^FS
^FT182,500^A0N,30,28^FH\^FD&IV_MATNR&^FS
^FT182,600^A0N,30,28^FH\^FD55281^FS
^FT39,700^A0N,28,25^FH\^FD\TARİH         :^FS
^FT182,700^A0N,30,28^FH\^FD&IV_BUDAT&^FS
^FT460,400^A0N,30,25^FH\^FDNET KG  :^FS
^FT460,500^A0N,30,25^FH\^FD\LOT       :^FS
^FT565,400^A0N,39,34^FH\^FD&IV_MENGE&^FS
^FT565,500^A0N,39,34^FH\^FD&IV_CHARG&^FS
^BY2,3,56^FT49,875^BCN,,Y,N
^FD>: &IV_BARCODE&^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ
```

[image]

My problem is about the Turkish character 'i'.
ıt doesn't print 'i' characters although ı wrote `^CI28`.

Answer (score 2):

Font 0 does not support the Turkish characters but zebra offers a free font, Swiss 721, which does.  The following PDF contains the character sets supported by Swiss 721:

https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/fonts/Swis721_BT_CharList.pdf

You can read more about the font and how to use it on zebra's site at:

https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/unicode-printing-using-the-free-swiss-721-font-for-zebra-zpl-printers.html